# Are questions about medical research protocols on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about medical research protocol on-topic?

Example:
[How is it determined that someone died from "air polution"?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/4125/43)

> I saw [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/31156/28873)
>   on another Stack Exchange site, and wondered, how do they even know
>   that one person in China died from "air pollution"?
>
> How do these "studies" that lump millions of people in to categories
>   know how to classify the deaths?  Do they categorically assume that
>   everyone with asthma that died was "killed by air pollution"?  if so,
>   wouldn't all such statistics be overstated from the start?

Comment: I would think it would be closed as to broad as the answer to how they get the answers would be very lengthy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't strictly dismiss a medical research question as off-topic, but we should definitely make sure that they are answerable (e.g. not too broad). So if a question links a specific article or a study and asks for an explanation, or the question is specific enough for a detailed, not too long answer, then it's fine. The important thing is that the question focuses on the part of research related to health. If it lists a set of numbers from a medical study and asks for clarification on statistics, I would refer them to a different SE site.